# Sample data using np.random.choice()

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am using the iris data set from sklearn to do some basic predictive modelling. I am splitting the data into training and test sets and  for a list of given proportions, I want to sample without replacement different proportions of the training data. I need to sample using **np.random.choice** **cannot use df.sample**

But what I am doing to sample seems to be incorrect. I will greatly appreciate any insights.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
iris = load_iris()
props=[0.2,0.5,0.7,0.9]
df = pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']],
                    columns= iris['feature_names'] + ['target'])
y=df[list(df.loc[:,df.columns.values =='target'])]
X=df[list(df.loc[:,df.columns.values !='target'])]
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3
                                       ,train_size=0.7)
for i in proportions:
   sampleX=np.random.choice(X_train, size=i, replace = False) #----> code to sample
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sample the index:

```
props=[0.2,0.5,0.7,0.9]
for i in props:
    ix = np.random.choice(X_train.index, size=int(i*len(X_train)), replace = False)
    sampleX = X_train.loc[ix]
```

Or simply use a binomial:

```
for i in props:
    sampleX = X_train.iloc[np.random.binomial(1,i,len(X))]
```

Comment: Although this samples perfectly, it is sampling with replacement.

Comment: surprising coz replace is set to False. I tried to set random_state in the test_train_split() but that also did not work

Comment: what do you mean by it samples with replacement, you realize that you are overwriting `sampleX` with each iteration right

Comment: if you do np.random.choice or np.random.binomial, every row is used once. It is impossible to have repeats